# Angular 2 Unexpected value 'MyDirective' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am trying to create npm library with one directive and test it locally with the help of npm link.

But the problem is when I am including my directive in the declarations array I am getting this error:

> Unexpected value 'MyDirective' declared by the module 'AppModule'

My library structure:

**package.json**

```
 {
   "name": "my-directive",
   "main": "./dist/index.js",
   "typings":  "dist/index.d.ts"
 }
```

**My src folder:**

**index.ts**

```
export * from "./myDirective";
```

**myDirective.ts**

```
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "my-directive"
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor() {
    console.log('directive works!');
  }
}
```

Now in my Angular 2 app that I'm linking this npm package:

```
import { MyDirective } from "my-directive";

// This line indeed log the constructor function...
console.log(MyDirective);
 // function MyDirective() {
    // console.log('directive works!');
 // }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyDirective
  ]
})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is it `myDirective.ts` or `my-directive.ts`?

Comment: The file name is myDirective and the package name is my-directive

Comment: export * from "./my-Directive";

Comment: The directive file name is myDirective.ts so I need to export * from "./myDirective";

Comment: "typings":  "./dist/index.d.ts"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue and I don't know exactly why, but in the **package.json** file, remove the Angular 2 dependencies from the dependencies field to devDependencies solve this problem and my npm module worked.

You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion and a PR regarding similar issues here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2291

See if this might help.